# How can I edit a tag in a parsed XML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I got the XML content with this and save into an other var:

```
  $.get("content.xml",function(d){
    ....
    xml=d;
  }
```

Some code later:

```
  $("tag_name_inXML",xml).text("new_content");
  alert($("tag_name_inXML",xml).text()); //alerts the original content..why?
```

I've also tried this:

```
 $(xml).find("tag_name_inXML").text("new_content");
 alert($(xml).find("tag_name_inXML").text()); //also alerts the original content..why?
```

I just want to parse an XML, edit it and save it via PHP.

I also tried this:

```
  $.get("content.xml",function(d){
    ....
    xml=$(d); 
  }
  ...
  xml.find("tag_name_inXML").text("new_content");
  alert(xml.find("tag_name_inXML").text());//Alerts the NEW! content but..
```

...I can't send it by

```
  $.get("save_xml.php",{xml_send:xml});
```

I got TypeError: Illegal Invocation

I've run out of ideas...

Comment: dont edit the xml on the client side period!

Answer (score 2):

You just need convert the `xml`, which is a jQuery object, to a string including the changed xml.

Following your these code:

```
$.get("content.xml",function(d){
    ....
    xml=$(d); 
  }
  ...
  xml.find("tag_name_inXML").text("new_content");
  alert(xml.find("tag_name_inXML").text());//Alerts the NEW! content but..
```

Try change `xml` to `xml[0].outerHTML`:

```
$.get("save_xml.php",{xml_send:xml[0].outerHTML});
```

Comment: I tried it but it deletes the entire xml doc, so it writes into the file the nothing.

Comment: What does `it deletes the entire xml doc` mean? Did `xml[0].outerHTML` have any value?